# Read Text with conditions

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

[sample1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpLxP.jpg)

ID Name    Age
    1   Amila   31
    2   Jaya    28
    3   Sahan   24
    4   Ishara  21

This is my sample1.text file with 3 columns. I want to read the file and write only persons with age greater than 25.

Can you please help to with the best way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the string.Split method to add your elements to an array or list.

For for tabs it'd look like `yourString.Split("\t")` and for commas `yourString.Split(",")`

More info on the Split here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks @Sean for your kind support. I have posted my answer. If there's any changes or any best solution other than this, please help me learn.

Answer (score 0):

How I would tackle this

- Read the lines from the sample file using `File.ReadAllLines(@"FilePath")` and store them in a list.
- Create a StreamWriter for writing the values you want to the Output File
- If you want the headers in the output file then write the headers and then remove them from the list.
- Have a loop that will split the line with `line.split('\t')`, check the age for that line, and write the line if it matches the condition using `output.writeline("Stuff to write")`

**After Looking at Your Progress**

Move the `using(var writer=new StreamWriter(WritePath))` to above `string s ="";` since you are only writing the last line of the original file.

You are basically overwriting the file with each line read instead of appending.

Inside the while loop you can check the age and then write the lines you want in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your kind support. I have posted my answer. If there's any changes or any best solution other than this, please help me learn.